# Multiple Jquery ui autocomplete on one page

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery

I'm using the [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). I'm using it on three different input. So I have:

> **input id 1**
> autocomplete with xml data 1
>
> **input id 2**
> autocomplete with xml data 2
>
> **input id 3**
> autocomplete with xml data 3

I also have an event like this:

```
$(".ui-autocomplete li a").live("click",function(){

    doSearch($(this).text());

});
```

The problem is that this event takes place on all three of the autocomplete.

What do I have to change in the event code or elsewhere to bind the event to a specific input/autocomplete. So I want to have event 1, 2, 3 corresponding to the different sets of input/autocomplete.

Comment: You mean in the function `doSearch()` you'd like to know which dataset to use depending on the autocomplete which triggered the event ?

Comment: @Didier Ghys Im not sure what you mean by "autocomplete which triggered the event" as far as I know the autocomplete does not trigger the click event. Its the click that does:) But I think you are looking at the problem fron another angle, which is good, whatever gets the job done; so click on li 1 would do doSearch 1. You would say just changing the name of doSearch but I tried that, it doesnt work.

Comment: I meant the event you bind on the anchors (not really triggered by the autocomplete - sorry that confused you). But I think you don't have to bind an event yourself, use the built-in [select](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select) event.

Comment: @Didier Ghys I already took out the click event and tried it with the option 'select' I tried this for one autocomplete, I also changed the functions in to doSearch1,2 and 3. So the second an third autoc. dont have any event (click or select) The weird thing is that when 'select: doSearch1 (this(text))' it still performs a search with doSearch 2 and 3. (Which is not logical at all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to pass either the autocomplete element or its index to `doSearch()`, in addition to the item text.

Passing the autocomplete element is as simple as using [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
function doSearch(autocomplete, itemText)
{
    // ...
}

$(".ui-autocomplete li a").live("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    doSearch($this.closest(".ui-autocomplete"), $this.text());
});
```

Passing its index is a little trickier and can be achieved with [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

```
function doSearch(autocompleteIndex, itemText)
{
    // ...
}

$(".ui-autocomplete li a").live("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    doSearch($this.closest(".ui-autocomplete").index(".ui-autocomplete"),
        $this.text());
});
```

Note in passing that `bind()`, `delegate()` and `live()` have been superseded by [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) since jQuery 1.7, so you might want to use it to register your handler:

```
$(document).on("click", ".ui-autocomplete li a", function() {
    // ...
});
```

If your autocomplete elements have a common non-dynamic ancestor, you can also apply `on()` to that element instead of `document` to gain a little performance.

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem and explaining in such detail:)